# iText opens PDF, unable to read content

Tags: pdf, itext

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("E:\\document\\6imm5562e.pdf");
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader);
String textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(doc.getPage(1));
System.out.println(textFromPage);
```

The error message is as follows:

> Please wait...
>
> If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document.
>
> You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or Linux® by visiting  http://www.adobe.com/go/reader_download.
>
> For more assistance with Adobe Reader visit http://www.adobe.com/go/acrreader.
>
> Windows is either a registered trademark or a trademark of Microsoft Corporation in the United States and/or other countries. Mac is a trademark 
>   of Apple Inc., registered in the United States and other countries. Linux is the registered trademark of Linus Torvalds in the U.S. and other countries.

Comment: Extremely likely that it's an xfa form. Pure xfa form pdfs (in contrast to hybrid xfa/acroform form pdfs) usually do have the content quoted in the question as actual and only pdf content. Merely pdf processors that also serve as xfa processors replace that pdf content by rendering the xfa to display the file

Comment: You have also opened a Pull Request on the iText 7 repository on GitHub, but your PR did not contain any code changes, you only merged `develop` into `master`. We will proceed to close your Pull Request, as we prefer to use Stack Overflow for community support. Thank you for using iText!

Comment: error pdf download url: https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5562e.pdf

Comment: Yes, it is an XFA form. So the text you saw is really the text. If you want to convert the XFA form into text, you'll have to use some XFA related methods of itext.

Comment: What should I do? Do you have any relevant documents

Comment: do you want to extract the information present on the form (filled out by someone), or from the "static" PDF?

Answer (score 1):

It is not 100% clear what data you would like to extract, so I will provide with two choices:

1) You want to extract the *static* text from the PDF (this solution requires [pdfXFA](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfxfa), by using the [flatten method](https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfXFA/java/2.0.4/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/xtra/xfa/XFAFlattener.html#flatten-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-)):

```
public void readXFA() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    final XFAFlattener xfaFlattener = new XFAFlattener();
    xfaFlattener.flatten(new FileInputStream(INPUT_XFA),
            new FileOutputStream(FLATTENED));

    final PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(FLATTENED));
    String textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(doc.getPage(1));
    System.out.println(textFromPage);
}
```

this code will first flatten your form, and then use your code on the flattened PDF file.

2) You want to extract data that was filled on the form (for that, you only need iText 7 Core, and the method [getXfaFieldValue](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.9/com/itextpdf/forms/xfa/XfaForm.html#getXfaFieldValue-java.lang.String-)):

```
public void readXFA() throws IOException {
        final String INPUT_XFA = "c:\\temp\\imm5562e.pdf";

        try (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(INPUT_XFA))) {
            XfaForm xfaForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, false).getXfaForm();
            System.out.println(xfaForm.getXfaFieldValue("TextField2"));
        }
    }
```

I guess technically, you can use the first approach to extract both the data, but then you'd lose the power of XFA to extract data from a form.

Comment: This is com.itextpdf: pdfxfa: 2.0.4?

Comment: System.out.println(xfaForm.getDomDocument());  --->  [#document: null]

Comment: Yes, this is with pdfXFA 2.0.4. Can you post the complete code of what you're trying to achieve? If you use the code I've posted with the PDF you've shared, does it work?